# How read the images in DDRAGON LOL API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, loops, jsx

I am using this API: https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.4.1/data/en_US/champion.json

I can read well all the parameters (name, id, etc.) but when I want to show the images of the champ, it doesn't show.

Leave my code here, tried everything:

```
let elements = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  elements.push(
    <Champ
      nombre={this.state.champions.data.Akali.image[0]}
      img={this.state.champions.data.Akali.image.sprite}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you mind pasting some more code in your question so others have some context to answer your question?

Comment: API is not giving the absolute URL, it is only giving you name of the image

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem". People should not have to download or visit another site in order to understand the question. Please show enough example data from the API so that people can understand what the structure is, and enough of your code so they can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try adding `https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.4.1/img/champion/` to the front of the url.  For example, https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.4.1/img/champion/Aatrox.png - there is some documented Java code [here](https://gist.github.com/taycaldwell/9d3c25ef17b7ee97dc06) which says how to get the other entities.

Comment: For sprites the url is https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.4.1/img/sprite/champion0.png - so add the /img/sprite path for sprites.